# How to display a list of class objects in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a python list where each element in the list is the object of a class:

```
message = [
    <File(tar_file:appstream-glib-0.1.5.tar.xz, filename:/appstream-glib-0.1.5/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>, 
    <File(tar_file:totem-3.12.1.tar.xz, filename:/totem-3.12.1/build-aux/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
    <File(tar_file:gvfs-1.20.2.tar.xz, filename:/gvfs-1.20.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
    <File(tar_file:gnome-software-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/gnome-software-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
    <File(tar_file:gnome-packagekit-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/gnome-packagekit-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
    <File(tar_file:gnome-color-manager-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/gnome-color-manager-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
    <File(tar_file:gnome-chess-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/gnome-chess-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
    <File(tar_file:gnome-power-manager-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/gnome-power-manager-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
    <File(tar_file:evolution-mapi-3.12.2.tar.xz, filename:/evolution-mapi-3.12.2/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
    <File(tar_file:cockpit-0.7.tar.bz2, filename:/cockpit-0.7/tools/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
    <File(tar_file:xf86-video-freedreno-1.1.0.tar.bz2, filename:/xf86-video-freedreno-1.1.0/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>, 
    <File(tar_file:elfutils-0.159.tar.bz2, filename:/elfutils-0.159/config/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>,
    <File(tar_file:ibus-table-1.5.0.20140519.tar.gz, filename:/ibus-table-1.5.0.20140519/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>, 
    <File(tar_file:fence-agents-4.0.9.tar.xz, filename:/fence-agents-4.0.9/config.guess, sha256:4a86808b907403ad6801c0661a4524dfa07c0b898a2cef6e7fa0cf82a09b9c53)>
]
```

Type of each element of list is -> class `summershum.model.File`

I want to return the list as a response through flask and display its content on localhost but it does not display anything.

This is how I am doing it.

```
return flask.Response(
        response=message,
    )
```

What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: What do you expect to be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you typically return objects from a view to the template:

In your views method:

```
@app.route('/files')
def display_files():
    '''code to retrieve list of file objects'''
    return render_template('files.html', all_files=all_files)
```

Then in your template file, you can access `all_files` as:

```
  {% for a_file in all_files %}
      {{ a_file.tar_file }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Documentation on flask templates [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/templates/)